# How do variable current limiters work in power supplies?

Tags: power-supply, power, current, current-limiting, workbench

Bench top power supplies often enable you not only the set the voltage, but the maximum current.

How do these bench supplies provide this variable current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a broad question, so I'll give a broad answer.

Just like the control system in the supply measures the output voltage so that it can decide whether to crank the supply up or down to keep this voltage at the setpoint, it also measures current and cranks the supply down if the measured current exceeds the setpoint.

Basically the supply regulates to a fixed voltage or a fixed current, *whichever it encounters first*.

Comment: So that's why the supply's voltage will drop if you make it to the current limit.  What types of discrete components does it use to limit the current?

Comment: Yes, the output voltage will necessarily drop if the load tries to draw more current than the current limit is set to.  At that point, the supply regulates its current output instead of voltage output.  As for the circuit topology, there are many.  Modern supplies generally are switchers with microcontrollers running the control loop.  The current limit feature is thererfore implemented in firmware, aside from the current needing to be measured, which it often is for other reasons anyway.